# Drop List problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a drop down list with 2 sub categories. When I open the first one, it opens seamlessly, but whenever I open the second one, near the bottom, the categories do not expand fully. I have my section of code on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS9KD/), and if someone could take a look, that would be much appreciated. I think it's a problem with my jQuery, but it could just as easily be my HTML, so that's why I've included everything germane to my drop down list. Specifically my problem lies with the 2013 category.

Here's my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_container').click(function(){
        if( $(this).parent().is('.open') ){
                $(this).closest('.tabSlot').find('.tab_container_expanded').animate({'height' : '0'},500);
                $(this).closest('.tabSlot').removeClass('open');
        }else{
            var newHeight =$(this).closest('.tabSlot').find('.tabs_expanded').height() + 'px';
            $(this).closest('.tabSlot').find('.tab_container_expanded').animate({'height' : newHeight},500);
            $(this).closest('.tabSlot').addClass('open');
        }

    });



});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_containerb').click(function(){
        if( $(this).parent().is('.open') ){
                $(this).closest('.tabSlotb').find('.tab_container_expandedb').animate({'height' : '0'},500);
                $(this).closest('.tabSlotb').removeClass('open');
        }else{
            var newHeight =$(this).closest('.tabSlotb').find('.tabs_expandedb').height() + 'px';
            $(this).closest('.tabSlotb').find('.tab_container_expandedb').animate({'height' : newHeight},500);
            $(this).closest('.tabSlotb').addClass('open');

        }

    });



});
```

I feel like I need another statement in the second function that I just can't figure out, but that's just what I'm thinking.

Comment: The .tab_container_expanded parent the expanded .tab_container_expandedb must also have the height adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using heights to control the menu and the height is not properly calculated when you have sub elements with height equal to `0`.

I changed your code to use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` and using `display: none;` instead of  `height: 0;` and it worked.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramynasr/5kcdP/).

Comment: I have one question though, did you do anything to the HTML? I've modified the CSS and the jQuery, but I need to know if I should edit  the HTML

Comment: No I did not touch the HTML, just tidied it up but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem hide in your css, 
instead of you overflowed hidden and hight 0, you should use display:none, instead
because the fixed hight in your query is not enough to show all the sub-menu item. 
so use $.show() instead.

Comment: Could you possible show an example of what you mean for the jQuery part?

Comment: this is just a lazy example i did, but use it to implement in your code http://jsfiddle.net/zS9KD/1/